# There exist $a,b$ integers such that $a³+b³=311$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, divisibility

The title says it all. I know $a$ and $b$ can't be zero because 311 is prime. What can I do next?

Comment: Can you factor $x^3 + y^3$?

Comment: HINT: One of $a$ and $b$ could be negative.

Comment: Well, then $x^3 + y^3 = (x + y)(x^2+y^2-xy)$. I think that implies that at least one of the terms has to be $311$ and the other $1$, or then $311$ would not be prime. Now I'm stuck again.

About the possibility of $ab<0$, I can't figure out how to use that fact.

Comment: A priori, the two factors could also be negative. Here it's easy to see that $x^2 + y^2 -xy \geqslant 0$, so indeed one factor must be $1$, the other $311$. So either $x+y = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 - xy = 311$, or $x + y = 311$ and $x^2 + y^2 - xy = 1$. Try with $x+y = 1$ first.

Answer (score 4):

$311\equiv 3\pmod 7$

But $a^3\equiv 0,1,6\pmod 7$ for $a=0..6$ thus $a^3+b^3\in\{0,1,2,5,6\}\neq 3$

Thus it has not integer solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first factor $$a^3 +b^3$$= $$(a+b)* (a^2-ab+b^2)$$ so one of the factor must be 1 and another 311. From that we can say that a or b must be negative because a+b or $(a^2-ab+b^2)$ cant be 1 in other case. Can you continue now?

Comment: beware not to omit the couple (-1,-311) also.

Comment: Of course both of them cant be negative.Exactly one of them must be negative.

Comment: I meant $311=1\times 311=(-1)\times(-311)$ so $a+b$ can take $4$ different values.

Comment: Becase of the fact that $a^2+b^2-ab$ is always >0 so (-1,-311) cannot be the factors.

Answer (score 1):

$$a^{3}+b^{3}=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$
since 311 is prime number, such that there only four combinations
$$a+b=1;\quad a^2-ab+b^2=311\quad\quad\quad\quad(1)$$
$$a+b=311;\quad a^2-ab+b^2=1\quad\quad\quad\quad(2)$$
$$a+b=-1;\quad a^2-ab+b^2=-311\quad\quad\quad\quad(3)$$
$$a+b=-311;\quad a^2-ab+b^2=-1\quad\quad\quad\quad(4)$$
you can solve all the four equation set, it is clear that no integers satisfy the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with inequalities.  Suppose WLOG, $a\geq b$.  There are two cases:

Case 1:  $b$ is positive.  Then $a^3 \leq 311$, so $a\leq 6$.  If $a=5$ then $a^3+b^3 <311$, and $a=6$ doesn't work, so there are no solutions here.

Case 2:  $b$ is negative.  So replace $b$ by $-b$ and write $a^3 = 311 +b^3$.   Notice that $(b+1)^3 = b^3+3b^2 + 3b +1$,  so if $3b^2+3b+1 >311$, there can't be a cube in the range $b^3$ to $b^3+311$.

So $b<10$.  Check $311+b^3$ for $b=1, 2, \ldots, 9$ and find again, no solutions.